# I have a folder in git need to delete it

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have cloned the repo from remote.Now I have code in git local repsoitory. I want to delete a folder which consists of some binaries. I tried to use the command

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FOLDERNAME" HEAD

git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch foldername" -- --all
```

its rewriting the sha1 but not deleting. Need to delete, Need the commit history.

Comment: delete like remove from git history or just delete?

Comment: You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @RC  Remove from git history.

Comment: @ravan Does commit exists with that folder on remote repo or only in your local copy?

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the folder locally and then push, ex:

```
rm -rf folder
git add .
git commit -a -m "removed folder"
git push origin master
```

if you delete the folder permanently from history you can,

```
Step 1: Create a clone of the repository. ...
Step 2: Find the files that you want to remove. ...
Step 3: Rewrite history and remove the old files.
```

Comment: Ya Hossain. But it will delete and need with commit history.And also it should clear the space occupied.

Comment: Didnt dv, but this will **not** remove the folder from history. If one - by accident - stored credentials in it, a hacker can still obtain them.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem my bad i pushed some binaries which are not needed on to the remote.Because of that its giving problems whikle cloning to local.

Comment: @MSHossain This does not really answer the question. The question is about how to delete from git history

Comment: So what you suggest do you ahve any palns. @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: these command remove the folder from git... but if you want to delete permanently from history you can Step 1: Create a clone of the repository. ...
Step 2: Find the files that you want to remove. ...
Step 3: Rewrite history and remove the old files.

Comment: git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD

Comment: The above comment will rewrite and delete folder right? In my case its not deleting